# Hidden characters between everything in curl_exec response

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am picking up some legacy code from another developer. It's a middleman script that passes XML data between systems via `curl`. All of a sudden, the XML that it's returning contains strange characters between everything, rendering it invalid XML:

[image]

If I bypass the PHP script in question and post the data directly to the other system, it returns valid XML, so it seems to be a problem with the PHP script.

Below is the `curl` code:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml->asXML());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
array(
    'Content-Type: text/plain',
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $token)
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Echoing `$result` is what contains the invalid XML.

Again, if I post directly to `$url` via Postman, I get the correct and valid XML.

I tried changing the `Content-Type` to `application/xml`, but that didn't help.

Is there an encoding issue that has perhaps been introduced by a server or PHP update?

Thank you

Comment: That looks like UTF-16 misinterpreted as single byte encoding. In fact, you can spot the encoding declaration in the XML itself.

Comment: Interesting... if I set the encoding to UTF-16 via `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-16');` it still has those characters.

Comment: You are setting the `Content-Type` header incorrectly BTW. You are not posting plain text.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is a raw UTF-16 stream. Your application is most likely using UTF-8.

I'm sure the server will not change the output encoding per your request and I'm not aware of any means to handle it right from Curl, so you'll need to do the conversion yourself:

```
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding($result, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16'));
```

However, it's possible that your XML processor will handle it nicely out of the box. SimpleXML certainly does.

---

> if I set the encoding to UTF-16 via `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-16');` it still has those characters

That sets the [`Accept-Encoding` request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) and also instructs Curl to decode the response. This is meant to handle compressed data, it's unrelated to text encoding (plus you're requesting UTF-16, precisely the encoding you don't accept).